# PHP error - Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php

I created an array using sessions in PHP and I'm trying to print out the values of individual array elements but I'm getting the error specified in the title of the post:

*Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string*

Below is my code:

```
 foreach($_SESSION['items'] as $key => $value){
        
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>".$value['itemID']."</td>
                <td>".$value['amount']."</td>
             </tr>
        ";
        
    }
```

The error I'm encountering seems to be occurring on these two lines:

```
<td>".$value['itemID']."</td>
<td>".$value['amount']."</td>
```

Just wondering why this is occurring?

Comment: This error means that `$value` is a string but you are treating it as if it were an array.

Comment: @zineryt Check the value of `session` with offset `item` if seems to return a string

Answer (score 0):

$value['itemID'] is just a string value, and what you are doing is trying to access the way you would an associative array.

Not sure what the exact logical structure you are trying to achieve is, but just to fix the error, this will fix the error:

```
<td>".$value."</td>
```

Comment: you changed the question! you don't need just make the Error disappear it must be fixed in session initial or somewhere!